# How Does Deeplinking Work in The ThunderCore Hub Wallet?

Tags: thundercore

- Can I create deeplinks that would directly open a particular web page?
- Are those links sharable?

Answer (score 1):

The ThunderCore Hub wallet supports deeplinking to arbitrary URLs through the URL https://ttsite.link/

## Sample Session

```
$ URL=https://www.google.com
$ printf $URL | base64 -w 0 | printf 'https://ttsite.link/'$(cat)'\n'
https://ttsite.link/aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbQ==
```

`base64` is from GNU coreutils. You can also use e.g. python:

```
printf $URL | python3 -c 'import sys,base64;print(base64.b64encode(sys.stdin.buffer.read()).decode("ascii"))' | 
printf 'https://ttsite.link/'$(cat)'\n'
```

Clicking on https://ttsite.link/aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbQ== on a mobile device with the ThunderCore Hub app installed would then open the URL in the app.